# (LWJGL) How to render a plain colored object with glBlendFunc() on

Tags: java, transparency, lwjgl, blend, blending

I've put the line

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

in my OpenGL initialization code so the transparent parts of my textures stay transparent. Now I want to add a simple colored object, without a texture. But I can't as long as I keep that line there. How do I use transparent textures, yet still keep the ability to use colored objects? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that a transparent texel is bind while you draw your quads. Don't forget to unbind any current texture (= bind to 0).
Also, check the current color (glColor() with alpha != 0)